# Carbide c++ 3.2 Attempt to get response from TraceCore timed out Error

Tags: symbian, carbide

I have Installed Carbide c++ 3.2 but there is problem when i Connect my Nokia500 using CODA debugging Agent iam getting error as **ATTEMP TO GET RESPONSE FROM TRACECORE TIMED OUT ERROR**.

please help me out....!